# Azure CLI aks install cli permission denied and sudo does not work

Tags: linux, sudo, azure-cli, azure-aks

I'm trying to run
`az aks install-cli`
 but I get an error that says

```
Downloading client to "/usr/local/bin/kubectl" from "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
Connection error while attempting to download client ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/kubectl')
```

If I use sudo I get:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Not sure how to elevate permissions other than using sudo

Comment: wasn't intending to, just didn't come back after i had figured that out. sorry!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to install the kubectl for AKS if you use the Azure Cloud Shell, that's a default tool installed in it. See [all the default tools installed in Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features#tools).

So you should take a look at the list if you want to install a tool in the Azure Cloud Shell.

And permissions are set as regular users without `sudo` access. Any installation outside your `$Home` directory is not persisted. So you cannot execute the `sudo` command in it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is expected. It tries to install it in /usr/local/bin which isnt user writable.

You need to either use: `sudo aks kubernetes install-cli`
OR
use the `--install-location` to install to another location.

There is an issue similar to this reported on `azure-cli` repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2558

Comment: Also, not sure which location I would install it to.

Comment: can you try `sudo az aks kubernetes install-cli`. And, create a directory `/home/ubuntu/.aks` and install it there.

Comment: Okay, so I'm using cloud shell actually. Maybe I don't need to run this command?

Comment: Or maybe use `az aks install-cli` - Downloads and installs kubectl, the Kubernetes command-line tool.

CloudCLI should have it installed, try `az aks list`

Comment: How did you go?

Answer (score 1):

I still get error when I run it in Azure Portal Cloud Shell Powershell window -
[image]

but as it is specified above kubectl is already installed. I ran kubectl commands directly after switching to BASH - it ran fine.
[image]